# why one number is larger than a identical number in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a program in which

```
e=0.01;    
test3=Ask(1,2)-Bid(1,2);
```

(`Bid` and `Ask` are both matrices generated by a for loop).

I know that sometimes test3 could equal to e, but matlab gave me this:

```
>>test3
e
test3==e
test3>e

test3 =

    0.0100

e =

    0.0100

ans =

     0


ans =

     1
```

What's wrong with it? Thank you!

EDIT: I tried `format long` and then I got

```
Ask(1,2) =

   8.620000000000001

Bid(1,2) =

   8.609999999999999

test3 =

   0.010000000000002
```

no wonder I got it wrong. But actually I've already use `price=roundn(r*v,-2)` and both `Ask(1,2)` and `Bid(1,2)` equal to some `price` so they should have two decimal places only. What can I do now if I want to round them to exactly two decimal places? Thanks again!

Comment: Try entering `format long` at the MATLAB command prompt and then re-run your test.

Comment: To determine why this is happening, print `format long g; disp(test3 - e)`

Comment: Thanks! I know that they are different now..

Comment: @Natalia, use the abs(x-y)<eps formulation from my answer below to compare to a known number of digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, roundoff error makes it difficult to ever compare numbers in floating point.

0.1 is a nice decimal number 1/10, but stored on a computer in binary it is a repeating fraction and not stored exactly.

So just for example:

```
x = 0.2;
y = 0.1 + 0.1;
x == y
```

will not be true.

[Well, unfortunately, as rwong points out below, this actually isn't true.  I should have tried it! Octave is being a bit too smart for me at this hour.  Still, in general, there will be roundoff!]

Sometimes the error will be big enough to see in the 16th digit, which is why you got the comment to try format long.  But sometimes it might not be visible.  The bottom line is:

NEVER USE == for two decimal numbers.  It is almost always false, and usually that's meaningless.

what you want is to test if two numbers are very close to each other, which is:

abs(x-y) < 0.00001

for some small limit.

Comment: For the `x == y` test, MATLAB actually prints true... (because it uses a tolerance for comparisons.)

Comment: Ouch! Actually, it's using extra bits internally because x-y is zero.  I know I've hit this before, but I've been trying to create a roundoff error and am having trouble for a simple example! (in Octave)

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question just now. Can I actually round them to two decimal places?

Comment: Your example is buggy: it is of the form x/2 + x/2, which is always equal to x in a binary floating-point arithmetic (well, except in case of underflow or overflow) because all the operations are here exact. The tolerance for comparisons doesn't matter here.

Comment: @vinc17 good point, but 0.1+0.1+... ten times == 1.0 which should not be true.  So there are extra digits (on Intel architecture) hiding what would normally be a great demonstration of roundoff error.

Comment: @Dov With this new example, == returns true probably due to some tolerance as rwong said. But http://www.mathworks.fr/help/matlab/ref/eq.html doesn't mention any tolerance with == and suggests to use `abs(x-y) < eps` (see the "Compare Floating-Point Numbers" example). So, I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

If `test3 = 0.01000000000000001` or some such and `e = 0.01` then you are likely to get this sort of result what happens when you print `test3-e` will give you a clue - this is why in the safety critical field float == float is always something that raises an alarm bell with auditors.

Comment: Your example has a few digits too many.  double precision is 16 digits.